# Constness with std::unordered_set & transparent hash

Tags: c++, unordered-set

Suppose I have a type whose values I want to store in a `std::unordered_set` that looks like this:

```
struct S {
    int key; // key is conceptually a part of S and S needs access to it. 
    int data;
    
    bool operator==(S const& rhs) const { return key == rhs.key; }
    bool operator==(int key) const { return this->key == key; }
};
```

and an accompanying hasher

```
struct SHash {
    using is_transparent = void;
    // Assume std::hash<int> is the identity function. 
    size_t operator()(S const& s) const { return s.key; }
    size_t operator()(int key) const { return key; }
};
```

Now I can lookup values in the hashtable by their keys:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<S, SHash, std::equal_to<>> s;
    s.insert(S{ .key = 0, .data = 1 });
    s.insert(S{ .key = 1, .data = 2 });
    assert(s.find(0)->data == 1);
}
```

However I cannot change the values in the hashtable:

```
s.find(0)->data = 3; // Does not compile
```

This is expected and makes a lot of sense since changing the *key* would corrupt the hashtable and the returned iterator cannot know what my key *is* or what my hasher is actually hashing.

Now if I need to modify the rest of the `S` object, I can either

- use `std::unordered_map` (which internally is more or less an `unordered_set` of `std::pair`'s) and accept to store the key twice
- cast away const-ness of the reference returned by `.find()` and just hope that I will always remember not to change the key. I'm pretty certain that `const_cast` used like that would be legal as long as I don't change the key, but it feels really sketchy.
  **Edit:** `const_cast` is definitely not legal because it violates the contract mandated by the standard library. I'm just really certain that despite that everything would compile and run just fine.

Both options aren't really beautiful. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Note that using `operator==` like this isn't really best practice and just done to keep the example terse.

Play around with [the code](https://godbolt.org/z/aT4qK57fc) on Godbolt if you like.

Comment: cast away constness is not allowed. You could make the member `mutable`.

Comment: i mean you can cast away constness but if something is const then it is const and you cannot modify it it and a `const_cast` does not change that

Comment: it seems as if you should move to `std::unordered_map` because it allows indexing by an arbitrary key but also setting the value of the data

Comment: As long as you are using C++17 or newer you can `extract` the  node containing the object out of the set, modify it, and then `merge` it back in once done.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I understand it like this: If `std::unordered_set` _declares_ the value as const, than it would be forbidden, but it most probably doesn't. It just enforces const-ness through the interface.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, that sounds like a viable solution.

Comment: So you mean s.find(0) will return an iterator that would point to a `const S`?

Comment: No, I mean `s.find(0)` will return a const iterator which actually points to a mutable `S`

Comment: what difference does it make whether the interface ensures you only ever get to see a `const` element or the element is `const`. I wasnt aware of `extract` though, seems like the way to go

Comment: Interesting, I tried `std::cout << std::is_const_v<decltype(s.find(0))>;` but it doesn't print 1.

Comment: @kiner_shah ["Container elements may not be modified (even by non const iterators) since modification could change an element's hash and corrupt the container. "](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The difference is that casting constness away from a reference is allowed if the object it points to is not `const`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I was wondering how is that ensured if not through const. Maybe some internal constraints. Sorry if this is not related to the actual question.

Comment: @kiner_shah its ensured by documentation and specification stating that you cannot modify it. Remember that also `const` is for the one writing the code to help avoid mistakes and accidentally modify a constant object. You "can" `const_cast` and modify something that is constant, but then you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify elements in the `unordered_set`. Even with non const iterators you cannot modify them. I am not sure if they are `const` but in any case they are effectively constant. You cannot modify them. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> Container elements may not be modified (even by non const iterators) since modification could change an element's hash and corrupt the container.

What you want to do can be done via `std::unodered_set::extract`. The example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/extract):

> ```
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string_view>
> #include <unordered_set>
>  
> void print(std::string_view comment, const auto& data)
> {
>     std::cout << comment;
>     for (auto datum : data)
>         std::cout << ' ' << datum;
>  
>     std::cout << '\n';
> }
>  
> int main()
> {
>     std::unordered_set<int> cont{1, 2, 3};
>  
>     print("Start:", cont);
>  
>     // Extract node handle and change key
>     auto nh = cont.extract(1);
>     nh.value() = 4; 
>  
>     print("After extract and before insert:", cont);
>  
>     // Insert node handle back
>     cont.insert(std::move(nh));
>  
>     print("End:", cont);
> }
> ```

You cannot modify the elements in the container, but you can extract it, modify, and insert back in.

Comment: Thank you, this will probably be the way to go then. It does however seem to be a case where the standard is overly restrictive, as I could just implement a hash table myself and allow that specific kind of behaviour.

Comment: @chrysante you can still make the member `mutable`. Its not nice design, but I see no reason why it should not work

Comment: Yes, it's not nice design and also it's very intrusive on the interface, because I would also have to make all the mutating member functions `const`, which is just confusing to anyone reading the code.

Comment: Also aren't `mutable` members just syntactic sugar for `const_cast` on the `this` pointer? I mean if I make the key `mutable` and modify it, that can't be legal.